# Where to find file to edit <head> code

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a line of code on our site that uses HTTP which we need to change to https. It is in the  code.

Any idea which file we can find this code in to edit it?

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400italic,700,700italic%7cDroid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find here

- app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/YOUR_THEME_NAME/template/page/html/head.phtml
- System->Configuration->Design->Head and check the script there